# Pair each combination of two columns and calculate sum for a third column in data.table

Tags: merge, data.table, unique, key-value, cross-join

I have two very large df: df 1 and df2. Df 1 contains the columns "from", "to" and "count". The values in "from" and "to" represent commuting points and can occur multiple times:

| from1 | to1 | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10020 | 10020 | 20 |
| 10020 | 10020 | 10 |
| 10020 | 22001 | NA |
| 30030 | 20020 | 2 |
| 45001 | 32001 | 100 |
| 45001 | 32001 | NA |
| 45001 | 45001 | 1 |
| 90080 | 45002 | NA |

In df 2, I would like to create each possible combination for "from" and "to". Then, I would like to fill in a new column "count_total" the sum of commuters for each individual pair. If the combination does not occur in df 1, I would like to fill in 0. For NA, I would like to fill in 0. My desired output:

| from2 | to2 | count_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10020 | 10020 | 30 |
| 10020 | 22001 | 0 |
| 10020 | 20020 | 0 |
| 10020 | 32001 | 0 |
| 10020 | 45001 | 0 |
| 10020 | 45002 | 0 |
| 30030 | 10020 | 0 |
| 30030 | 22001 | 0 |
| 30030 | 20020 | 2 |

...

I tried the following, however, it did not sum up the values for "count_total" correctly.

```
    df2 <- CJ(from2 = unique(df1$from1), 
                to2 = unique(df1$to1))


    df2[, count_total := sum(df1$count[
             df1$from1 == from2 &
               df1$to1 == to2
                ]), by = .(from2, to2)]
```

What did I do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: OH is the idea to add and then remove NAs, or remove NAs and then add?

Comment: Before adding up the values of "count_total", I would like to replace NA with 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a merge-then-summarize:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
CJ(from2 = unique(df1$from1), to2 = unique(df1$to1)
  )[df1, count2 := i.count, on = .(from2==from1, to2==to1)
  ][, .(count2 = sum(c(0, count2), na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(from2, to2)]
#     from2   to2 count2
#     <int> <int>  <num>
#  1: 10020 10020     10
#  2: 10020 20020      0
#  3: 10020 22001      0
#  4: 10020 32001      0
#  5: 10020 45001      0
#  6: 10020 45002      0
#  7: 30030 10020      0
#  8: 30030 20020      2
#  9: 30030 22001      0
# 10: 30030 32001      0
# ---                   
# 15: 45001 22001      0
# 16: 45001 32001      0
# 17: 45001 45001      1
# 18: 45001 45002      0
# 19: 90080 10020      0
# 20: 90080 20020      0
# 21: 90080 22001      0
# 22: 90080 32001      0
# 23: 90080 45001      0
# 24: 90080 45002      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Load required packages
2. Process dt with [lazy_dt()](https://dtplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/lazy_dt.html), so we can use [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) functions on it
3. [Summarise](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html), to combine rows with the same from1 and to1
4. [Complete](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html) the data, which creates rows for every combination of from1 and to1, with default values of 0
5. Since it's now lazy, we call as.data.table() to have it actually do the work

```
pacman::p_load(data.table, dtplyr)

dt <- dt |> lazy_dt()

dt |> 
  summarise(count = sum(count, na.rm = TRUE), .by = c(from1, to1)) |>
  complete(from1, to1, fill = list(count = 0)) |> 
  as.data.table()
```

Output:

```
    from1   to1 count
 1: 10020 10020    30
 2: 10020 20020     0
 3: 10020 22001     0
 4: 10020 32001     0
 5: 10020 45001     0
 6: 10020 45002     0
 7: 30030 10020     0
 8: 30030 20020     2
 9: 30030 22001     0
10: 30030 32001     0
11: 30030 45001     0
12: 30030 45002     0
13: 45001 10020     0
14: 45001 20020     0
15: 45001 22001     0
16: 45001 32001   100
17: 45001 45001     1
18: 45001 45002     0
19: 90080 10020     0
20: 90080 20020     0
21: 90080 22001     0
22: 90080 32001     0
23: 90080 45001     0
24: 90080 45002     0
    from1   to1 count
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `set()`:

```
library(data.table)

df2 <- df1[, CJ(from1, to1, unique = TRUE)][, count := 0L]

# CJ has already created a key
for (i in 1L:nrow(df1)) {
  if (is.na(df1$count[i])) next
  row <- df2[df1[i], which = TRUE]
  set(df2, row, "count", value = df2[row, count] + df1$count[i])
}
```